# Uneven NSTableCellView Focus Ring

Tags: macos, focus, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I'm working on a small app that uses a view-based NSTableView to display contents. I'm using an NSTableCellView subclass as the contents for each cell, and I'm having a problem where the NSTableCellView looks terrible when selected. First, the left, top, and right sides all looks unevenly selected (notice how the right side is thicker than the top and left), and in addition, the bottom line of the focus ring doesn't even show up for any cells. Here is a link to the image of what it looks like:

[NSTableView cell picture](http://postimage.org/image/721aig4o9/)

I've tried messing around with focus rings to no avail, which leaves me pretty clueless as to what this could be. Thanks for any help with this!